# Send a string from C# app to PHP

Tags: c#, php, networking

I want to send string from my C# app to my PHP page and I tried some different solutions that i found in the internet. One of them is this:

C# code:

```
        string url = "http://localhost:8080/test.php";
        string str = "test";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        string Data = "message=" + str;
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

and PHP code:

```
foreach($_POST as $pdata)
echo $pdata;
```

But it's just a blank page. I dont know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used c# in a long time, but this should be the solution:

```
    string url = "http://localhost:8080/test.php";
    string str = "test";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "POST";
    string Data = "message=" + str;
    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] postBytes = utf8.GetBytes(Data);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    var sr = new StreamReader(resStream);
    string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

What I did was change the encoding from ASCII to UTF8. UTF8 is what `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` expects.

As for your php, I assume you have opening and closing brackets on your foreach method.

**Edit:**

Okay, well I noticed an error in your c#. You were getting the response stream twice. That might have caused some error, but here is how I would structure my php:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo $value . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but its still just a blank page

Comment: i guess my problem is my php code. because actually my php code is      foreach($_POST as $pdata)
{
echo " *** ".  $pdata." ***<br> ";
} and its still blank page

Comment: @user3142031 I updated and explained a potential error that I noticed in your c#.